# The limit $\lim_\limits{n\to{\infty}}\int_0^{1}\sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, special-functions

This is [Problem 11941](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/amm.html) in the *American Mathematical
 Monthly*.

> What can we say about the limit $\lim_\limits{n\to{\infty}}\int_0^{1}\sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} dx\ ?$

I think we need to use gamma and beta functions here. Again, the result may involve the Euler's constant.